# A long formula stopped the Macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I face a problem [Error 1004] when I run the macro, is is because I created a long formula?

Check these 3 screen-shots please

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

**UPDATE (copied from the comment)**

```vba
Sub Merge() ' *** Merge Macro *** ' 
    Range("Y2").Select 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-23]=1,RC[-2],IF(RC[-23]=2,RC[-2]&R2C24&R[1]C[-2],IF(RC[-23]=3,RC[-2]&R2C24&R[1]C[-2]&R[-23]=6,RC[-2]-2]&R2C24&R[2]C[-2]&R2C24&R[3]C[-2]&R2C24&R[4]C[-2]&R2C24&R[5]C[-2],IF(RC[-" &"-2])))))))))" 
    Range("Y2").Select 
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Y2:Y2272") 
    Range("Y2:Y2272").Select 
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) Avoid using `ActiveCell` and `Selection`. Use direct assign. And specify the worksheet. I.e. `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Y2").FormulaR1C1 = "your long formula"`. 2) The range address of 20kk cells seems to be wrong. Use `Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`. 3) Post the code line(s) like a text, not a screenshot. 4) Check the IFs nested level do not exceed the limitation. And look at SWITCH() function... Or use `=IF(B2>0,W2,"")&IF(B2>1,$X$2&W3,"")&IF(B2>2,$X$2&W4,"")&...`

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to use the new formula as a first solution, and this is the code: 
Sorry couldn't paste all of it, I forced to delete some of it

Sub Merge()
'
' Merge Macro
'

'
    Range("Y2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-23]=1,RC[-2],IF(RC[-23]=2,RC[-2]&R2C24&R[1]C[-2],IF(RC[-23]=3,RC[-2]&R2C24&R[1]C[-2]&R[-23]=6,RC[-2][-2]&R2C24&R[2]C[-2]&R2C24&R[3]C[-2]&R2C24&R[4]C[-2]&R2C24&R[5]C[-2],IF(RC[-" &"-2])))))))))"
    
Range("Y2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Y2:Y2272")

    Range("Y2:Y2272").Select

End Sub

Comment: does your formula work is you manually place into the cell? I guess the problem is with the formula, not with the macro

Comment: its working very well

Comment: and your formula is working very well, but it's the same problem,
Please could you help me to change this code

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/15tu1tlreelvflt/Code.txt?dl=0

Comment: you have `RC[-2]-2]` in the formula.  it should be `RC[-2]`

Comment: Hi @Akinaand
I tested the formula until the 5th IF and the macro worked well, but if I added more ifs, to the formula it will stop working with 1004 error. Is there a limit of if number used in the same formula?

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner
in fact I deleted some of the code because there is a limitation characters here
Thank you

Comment: Hi every body, Thank you very much for you help,
the problem was: "When I record a macro for inputing a long formula, bits of it tend to get cut off, so what I did fixed this corrupted

Comment: if you need to shorten your formula, I think you are saying: `=TEXTJOIN($X$2,TRUE,W2:OFFSET(W2,B2-1,0))`. I'm leaving it up to you to figure out what this does...

Comment: Hi @gns100
Thanks for you answer, in fact I don't have this function in my MS-Excel 2013